# Why does this query not count losses?

Tags: postgresql

I'm making a leaderboard for a game, and I decided to use ELO. I found this [article by Medium](https://elliotchance.medium.com/elo-rating-system-implemented-in-single-sql-select-9511bdff6434) that has a query that should generate the standings. I implemented it and everything is working except for that it doesn't count losses.

Here's my query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE p(current_game_number) AS (
    WITH game_ids AS (
SELECT DISTINCT games.id g,MAX(turns.updated_at) tmx FROM games
LEFT JOIN turns ON turns.game_id = games.id
WHERE meta LIKE '%pvp%over%'
AND deleted_at IS NULL
AND turns.updated_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 days'
GROUP BY games.id
), pre1 AS (
SELECT game_ids.*, player_one_score p1, player_two_score p2, u.username player1 FROM game_ids
LEFT JOIN turns ON turns.game_id = g
INNER JOIN games_users gu ON gu.game_id = g
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = gu.user_id
WHERE turns.updated_at = tmx
AND is_first = TRUE
)
, pre2 AS (
SELECT game_ids.*, player_one_score p1, player_two_score p2, u.username player2 FROM game_ids
LEFT JOIN turns ON turns.game_id = g
INNER JOIN games_users gu ON gu.game_id = g
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = gu.user_id
WHERE turns.updated_at = tmx
AND is_first = FALSE
), pre3 AS (
SELECT pre2.*, pre1.player1 FROM pre2
INNER JOIN pre1 ON pre1.tmx = pre2.tmx
), rd AS (
SELECT *,
    COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM pre3
GROUP BY g, tmx, p1, p2, player1, player2 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1



), plays AS (
SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS BIGINT) game_number, player1 p1name, p1 p1score, player2 p2name, p2 p2score FROM rd



),  players AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT p1name AS player_name
    FROM plays
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT p2name
    FROM plays
  )
  SELECT
    CAST(0 AS BIGINT)               AS game_number,
    player_name,
    1000.0 :: FLOAT AS previous_elo,
    1000.0 :: FLOAT AS new_elo
  FROM players
  UNION ALL
  (
    WITH previous_elos AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM p
    )
    SELECT
      plays.game_number,
      player_name,
      previous_elos.new_elo AS previous_elo,
      round(CASE WHEN player_name NOT IN (p1name, p2name)
        THEN previous_elos.new_elo
            WHEN player_name = p1name
              THEN previous_elos.new_elo + 32.0 * (p1score - (r1 / (r1 + r2)))
            ELSE previous_elos.new_elo + 32.0 * (p2score - (r2 / (r1 + r2))) END)
    FROM plays
      JOIN previous_elos
        ON current_game_number = plays.game_number - 1
      JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT
             pow(10.0, (SELECT new_elo
                        FROM previous_elos
                        WHERE current_game_number = plays.game_number - 1 AND player_name = p1name) / 400.0) AS r1,
             pow(10.0, (SELECT new_elo
                        FROM previous_elos
                        WHERE current_game_number = plays.game_number - 1 AND player_name = p2name) / 400.0) AS r2
           ) r
        ON TRUE
  )
)
SELECT
  player_name,
  (
    SELECT new_elo
    FROM p
    WHERE t.player_name = p.player_name
    ORDER BY current_game_number DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )                    AS elo,
  count(CASE WHEN previous_elo < new_elo
    THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END) AS wins,
  count(CASE WHEN previous_elo > new_elo
    THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END) AS losses
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM p
    WHERE previous_elo <> new_elo
    ORDER BY current_game_number, player_name
  ) t
GROUP BY player_name
ORDER BY elo DESC;
```

Since I only have read access to the database, I have to do this in a single select statement.

I tried to run it at first but it gave me an error saying that the output is a bigint but game_number is an int (this is weird because the article said it would work with postgres). I casted it to a bigint and it seemed to work until I noticed the losses were always zero, including those who have lost.

Comment: Can you connect to it using JDBC or something? This just seems super messy, and could be done much easier if you weren't constrained by SQL.

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for your table and some relevant content? Just like that article, including the INSERT statements. We can now only guess what data you have.